# Accessing Azure KeyVault in Local Environment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure resource group and a user managed identity which has access to my Azure KeyVault but I do not seem to understand how this should work locally. I want to access my dev environment keyvault when running my application locally and this is how I was able to make this work [CurrentSolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oB5g.png). What I ended up doing was creating a service principal and using the credentials to access the key vault only when in local environment. If the environment is dev, stage, or production then it will use the DefaultAzureCredential (user-managed identity).

It definitely works but it does not seem like the correct way of doing this. Is there any advice or pointers I can get to be able to do this is a better way? Thank you.

```
string keyVaultEndpoint = "KeyVaultUri";
        if (environment.EnvironmentName.ToLowerInvariant() == "localhost")
        {
            var client = new SecretClient(new(keyVaultEndpoint),
                new ClientSecretCredential("tenantId",
                "clientId",
                "clientSecret"));

            build.AddAzureKeyVault(client, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
        }
        else
        {
            //var secretClient = new SecretClient(new(keyVaultEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "clientId" }));
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new(keyVaultEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            build.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
        }

        Configuration = build.Build();
```

Comment: Are you using visual studio?

Comment: Please post the actual code snippet instead of the screenshot.

Comment: Share the image as code, so that it would be easier for others to try out.

Comment: @Coconut Yes I am using Visual Studio, I know I can give my personal account access to keyvault but that means I would have to give everyone on my team access to it as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri I updated it and added the code. Thank you. I did remove the client Ids but I had them hardcoded there as a test

Comment: @Human1, if you are going to give a service principal account access to the KV and share its credentials with the team, what is the harm in granting your team access to the keyvault then?  We created a security group with dev team membership, and granted the group the necessary key vault permissions.

Comment: @Greg Yes that makes a lot of sense. I guess by overthinking I did not give myself a chance to compare these situations. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are only using secrets and keys, you can use [Lowkey Vault](https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault/wiki) too. It won't help you with the if-else you have shared (in fact it can make it a bit worse) but you can avoid sharing credentials or relying on cloud resources while running tests or starting your app locally.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a better way, but if you are going to share the credentials of a service principal with your team, then you might as grant the team access - best way is to create a security group with your dev team as membership, and give the security group the minimum permissions needed for the key vault.